# Excel Query (VLookUp perhaps?)

Tags: excel, null, vlookup

Here is the scenario:

I have two columns.  One column contains 1638 rows (customers present in the system last week).  The second column contains 1488 rows (customers in the system this week).  This is not simply the difference of two numbers, as some customers have been added and some have been lost. For example, I know that there are 150 less customers in the system (1638-1488), but it's possible that 50 customers have been added and 200 have been lost.
My colleague told me to do a Vlookup, and where there are not matches from last week to this week, I'll see #null.  I could use a pivot table to make a sum of the #null's.

What's your thought?
Thanks in advance

Also, I hope I was clear.  If you need more info, I'd be glad to give it

Comment: What result do you want. A number of customers added and removed, or a list?

Comment: The desired result is a list of customers added, not a number. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Last 2 steps not necessary but good for formatting:

- add headings, thisWeek and lastWeek then pivot the results.
- Add thisWeek and lastWeek into the Row Labels area.
- Design Ribbon >> Report Layout >> Show in tabular format
- In pivot right click sub totals and remove.

Now you just filter for blanks to see customers not available. You can also drag the labels into the Values box to get a count (if required).

Answer (score 1):

MATCH would probably be a better choice than VLOOKUP for your requirements combined with an IF statement and ISNA.
I'm going to assume that the list of last week's customers are in column A and this week's are in column B.

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B2, A:A, 0)), "New Customer", "Old Customer")
```

This code takes the value from cell B2 and looks for it in column A. If it finds it, it returns "Old Customer" otherwise it returns "New Customer".
You can change the output from the IF statement to suit your purposes.

Comment: does not take into account if customers have left

Comment: Might be valuable to note: The two columns are not in the same numerical order.

Comment: The resulting list I'm getting is too high, I think.

Comment: The 0 in the third parameter of the MATCH statement ensures it only returns exact matches, list ordering is unimportant. Assuming that the formula is applied to a list of customers for a given week, customers who have left will never feature. To calculate customers who have left you need the total of customers previous week minus "Old Customers" from this week which you now have the capability to do.

Comment: So this will tell me customers in column A (This week) who are not in column b (last week)?

Comment: There doesn't need to be some sort of vertical search function?  That's why I was thinking it would be a vlookup.  Becuase I need it to search the entire column for the value.  If this MATCH statement does that, I agree that it would be the best method

Comment: Yup, MATCH is very similar to VLOOKUP in that it searches a range for a specified value. However, instead or returning a corresponding value, it just returns the number of the matching cell. I'd tend to use it in situations like this where the return value is irrelevant as I'm assuming it has a lower overhead.

Answer (score 1):

With Conditional Formatting is another option - no need to occupy any more than those cells already occupied.

Format `ColumnA` with  `=ISNA(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)` and `ColumnB` with `=ISNA(MATCH(B1,A:A,0)` and apply to ranges to suit.

(Assuming the two lists are in the first two columns.)

[image: SO13827174 example]

Lists of gains and/or losses could be extracted via Filter by Color and counts provided that way also.